# Remove all instances of token from comma separated list with regex

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have a list of comma separated tokens. I wish to remove all instances of a particular token using regex:

```
$str = "tok1,tok2,tok3";

if($new = preg_replace("/(tok2,|,?tok2)/","",$str)){
    echo $new;
}else{
    echo "Regex failed";
}
```

This works in all instances with the exception of `"tok2,tok2,tok2"` in which case the replacement actually fails. Why is the replacement failing in the above case and how might I fix it?

EDIT: I'm a complete idiot. My original regex worked as expected all along. I had intended to capture a null result from preg_replace in the event of error but failed to consider an emptry string would also evaluate to false. How do I close this question?

Comment: Does it have to be regex?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I'd add a why to your comment

Comment: While I appreciate the alternative solutions to regex, I wish to understand fully why my regex attempt fails before considering other solutions.

Comment: Does `'#((,|^)tok2|tok2(,|$))#'` work for your needs? Strangely enough I just tested the regex in your code and it works fine. [codepad](http://codepad.org/BrcKDzny) - See that it's using `$rex3` which is yours. What version are you running?

Comment: Re: your edit, you can't close a question after people have provided answers; you'd be deleting everyone's hard work.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are literally just removing one string with very fixed formats, i.e. "tok2," ot ",tok2", as Brad said, `str_replace` will be plenty good enough for the job.

Otherwise, a much more manageable solution (personally) would be to use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array_filter)

```
<?php
$str = "tok1,tok2,tok3,tok2,tok4,tok3";
$tokensToRemove = array('tok2','tok3');
$tokens = explode(',',$str);
$filteredTokens = array_filter($tokens,function($tok) use($tokensToRemove) { return !in_array($tok,$tokensToRemove); });

$newStr = implode(',',$filteredTokens);
var_dump($newStr);
```

Or if on an old PHP version:

```
<?php
$str = "tok1,tok2,tok3,tok2,tok4,tok3";
$tokensToRemove = array('tok2','tok3');
$tokens = explode(',',$str);
function removeTokens($tok)
{
    global $tokensToRemove;
    return !in_array($tok,$tokensToRemove);
}
$filteredTokens = array_filter($tokens,'removeTokens');

$newStr = implode(',',$filteredTokens);
var_dump($newStr);
```

You can then easily adjust `$tokensToRemove` and all instances will be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

If string manipulation is not mandatory, I would go with something like this:

```
 <?php
 $str = "tok1,tok2,tok3";
 var_dump(join(",", array_filter(explode(",", $str), function($s) { return $s !== "tok2"; })));
 ?>
```

Three steps:

- split on separator (`,` here)
- filtering out `"tok2"`
- join values using the separator (`,` again)

Answer (score 0):

Derived from my prior answer there is an easier way:

- Append a trailing `,`
- replace every `tok2,`
- remove trailing `,`

(the trailing `,` just ensures you match the `tok2,`, if it appears at the end of the string)

like this:

```
$str = "tok1,tok2,tok2,tok3,tok2";

//-----
$str =  $str.","; //append trailing ,
$str = preg_replace("/tok2,/","", $str); //replace every "tok2,"
$str = rtrim($str, ","); //remove trailing , 
//-----

echo $str;
```

and in one line of code:

```
$str = rtrim(preg_replace("/tok2,/","", $str.","), ",");
```

No magic required :-)

ps.: Would even work with

```
$str = rtrim(str_replace("tok2,","", $str.","), ",");
```

which *might* outperform **any** regex.

---

Yepp, way faster:

```
<?php

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++){
  $str = "tok1,tok2,tok2,tok3";
  $str = rtrim(str_replace("tok2,","", $str.","), ",");
} 
$time_elapsed_us = microtime(true) - $start;
echo "str_replace : " . $time_elapsed_us . "<br />";



$start = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++){
  $str = "tok1,tok2,tok2,tok3";
  $str = rtrim(preg_replace("/tok2,/","", $str.","), ",");
} 
$time_elapsed_us = microtime(true) - $start;
echo "preg_raplace : " . $time_elapsed_us;
?>
```

Outcome (1 Million replacements):

```
str_replace : 1.2485978603363
preg_raplace : 2.1617259979248
```